# Separating model concerns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, separation-of-concerns

Any given model in my application might implement the `IHasOpenGraphMetadata`, if that's the case, a call to `@Html.Partial("_OpenGraphMetadata")` in my layout will render the related metadata, by accessing the model through that interface.

All's good and clean. That is until I wanted to do that from a partial action.

In `/Home/Index` I have the following call: `@Html.Action("List", "Posts")`

This returns:

```
public ActionResult List(long? timestamp = null, int count = 8)
{
    IEnumerable<Post> posts = postService.GetLatest(timestamp, count);
    PostListModel model = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Post>, PostListModel>(posts);
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

The issue becomes apparent here: the actual model for `/Home/Index` is `null`, while the actual metadata is in the `/Posts/List` partial view result

I went with this in my partial which renders the `og:data` (`"_OpenGraphMetadata"`):

```
@{
    OpenGraphModel openGraph = GetOpenGraphMetadata();
    if (openGraph != null)
    {
        @OpenGraphMetaProperty("title", openGraph.Title)
        @OpenGraphMetaProperty("description", openGraph.Description)
        @OpenGraphMetaProperty("url", openGraph.Url)
        @OpenGraphMetaProperty("image", openGraph.Image)
    }
}
@helper OpenGraphMetaProperty(string property, string value)
{
    if (!value.NullOrBlank())
    {
        <meta property="og:@property" content="@value" />
    }
}
@functions
{
    private OpenGraphModel GetOpenGraphMetadata()
    {
        IHasOpenGraphMetadata model = Model as IHasOpenGraphMetadata;
        if (model != null)
        {
            return model.OpenGraph;
        }
        return Context.Items[Constants.OpenGraphContextItem] as OpenGraphModel;
    }
}
```

I figure this is pretty decent, try to extract the metadata from the actual model, and if the interface is not implemented, then access the `HttpContext` and look for the metadata there. The question now is, how should I be putting this metadata in the `HttpContext`?

I don't really want to pollute my action methods with calls like:

```
HttpContext.Items[Constants.OpenGraphContextItem] = model.OpenGraph;
```

But what other options do I have? Should I be doing this in a global action filter? a result filter? Is there an alternative to these options?

**Update**
It doesn't seem possible to do this in an action filter, the way I figured out I could do this was overriding the base controller's PartialView, and both View overloads, but this seems like a really unpolished approach, there must be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Why can't you use an action filter? You have access to the HttpContext from an action filter..

Comment: not to the model of child actions or partial views though.